# rosjava (on android) dependancies producing run-time errors

Tags: ros, nav-msgs, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently started working with ROS java and I've had decent success so far, however nav_msgs are not working. In my Android project I'm attempting to use OccupancyGrid from nav_msgs.  I included nav_msgs as a dependency in my manifest, ran rosmake, and have a nav_msgs  jar file.  I can reference the jar from my project and build the Andorid app, however, in run-time I get ClassNotFound exceptions when it tries to use nav_msgs.

Is there anything special that needs to be done to build jars for android?  My project used geometry_msgs and std_msgs without a problem.  Also, if I remove support for my map, thus eliminating the need for nav_msgs, my code base runs perfectly fine and the subscribers and publishers work as expected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11270/rosjava-(on-android)-dependancies-producing-run-time-errors/) by [johnfertitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/380/johnfertitta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2011-09-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out the jar is not bad after all.  I can create and use objects in nav_msgs without runtime errors.  The errors only occurred when I was trying to use OccupancyGrid with a service to retrieve a map.

This seems to be a problem with rosjava services and not with the compiled jar.

---

Originally posted by [johnfertitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/380/johnfertitta/) with karma: 89 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [johnfertitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/380/johnfertitta/) on 2011-09-30**:
I don't have one at the moment, but when I get a chance I'll try and post one.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-09-23**:
Do you have a stack trace by chance?